# SQL - transpose all categorical rows to columns and fill na

Tags: sql, hive

I have a database with data for different exams, for example:

```
Student Test Grade
--------------------
St1    T1   A
St1    T2   B
St2    T2   B
St2    T3   C
St3    T3   B
```

Then I would like to transpose column TEST, which has three category: T1 T2 and T3 to three columns and fill NA on not exist row

```
Student  T1   T2   T3
----------------------
St1      A    B    na
St2      na    B    C
St3      na    na    B
```

I don't know how to fill na on non-exist category
Any help is appreciated!